# How do emergency cash services work?

Tags: atms, emergencies

If you need emergency cash, do they send you some sort of code and you get the money from the ATM without any card? Or, do you have to show your ID at a local partner of the service to get cash? You would be screwed if you lose your ATM cards and IDs, which could often be the case.

Comment: I think it might depend on your provider. [Natwest give you a special code you enter into a cash machine](http://personal.natwest.com/personal/ways-to-bank-with-us/get-emergency-cash.html), but based on how much of a fuss their advertising makes of the feature, I think that's not all that common

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11569/is-visas-emergency-cash-disbursement-reliable

Comment: @EugeneO: that's surely related, although I care about how it is paid, and that question about when they decide to pay.

Comment: I know, I linked because it may have relevant info, e.g. one of the answers talks about getting the cash via Western Union. I agree that your question is separate, I'm not saying it's a duplicate or anything, I'm actually quite interested in the answer myself.

Comment: @EugeneO: yes, I just wanted to make sure that my question was not closed right away. Some people just from the hip and press the close button.

Comment: It used to be that you would go into a bank office and the teller would know to pay you on the agreed ID, (which was not necesarily a passport or bank card but had to be something only you could have.)

Comment: I still vote to close this as being far too broad. I am sure that the exact procedure both depends on your provider and where you need the emergency cash, and not just the country you are in, but even the exact location. A credit card issuer will for example likely have other possibilities to provide you quickly with emergency cash if you are in Beijing compared to the options available if you are in a village in rural China.

Comment: @Gagravarr The Natwest solution seems to be a proprietary solution within their own banking network, as you can't get the cash at any ATM, but only at some selected ATMs from operators within the RBS group.

Answer (score 3):

The general process is that:

1. You contact your scheme (eg Visa, Mastercard, American Express) and advise that you need emergency cash (because your card has been lost, stolen, damaged, etc). At this stage you provide certain information to them, commonly name, date of birth, address, SSN (if applicable), mother's maiden name and so on.
2. Your scheme will transmit this information to your issuing institution (if applicable), who will then have their own processes for verifying that you are who you say you are. They then either approve or decline this request.
3. If it is approved, your scheme will contact a wire transfer company - usually Western Union - and arrange for the emergency cash to be provided. They will separately give you information like a control number, and provide Western Union with information that you can verify yourself with in the event that you have lost your ID. This could be secret questions, for example.

   Alternatively, you can also, subject to your issuing institution's approval, authorise Western Union to release the funds to *someone else*. This could be someone you're travelling with who still has their ID, for example. Again, this depends on whether your issuing institution will approve this, but I've approved such requests in the past.

So, to address your question in brief: very rarely do you obtain the emergency cash from an ATM, generally you will obtain it from a wire transfer company; in the event you lose your ID, you still have options.

Comment: So, just to confirm, I won't get an emergency ATM card while traveling? And, I'd could be better off asking family and friends to wire me money through Western Union?

Comment: You _can_ get an emergency card while travelling but that is a separate/additional/different service - also, while you _could_ get family/friends to wire you money through WU if that's an option, this is a good fallback for those who don't have or can't get in contact with family/friends who can help.

Answer (score -4):

The latest common international banks practice needs you to activate your card for international use in advance. When you withdraw in another country, you need to key in your same pin.

Comment: That isn't true everywhere. Banks are moving away from this "pre-activation" requirement in the UK.

Comment: As you said in UK. Does UK represents the world? If as you said UK banks are moving away but have all banks had done this?

Comment: I am looking to localize your answer a little, because it doesn't align with my experiences. No doubt it is true in many cases; I am aware that the US banks are very paranoid about foreign transactions. Are banks of any other particular country like this as well? UK banks no longer consider foreign transactions suspicious.

Comment: I am afraid most banks in the world are like this because there are too many cases of hackings, misused, stolen, and all sorts of funny cases in the world using other people's cards or accounts. Banks are also business entity so who will be responsible if an account is hacked? By using this system, it had proven massively reduced the amount of cases happened.

Comment: Could you expand your answer with the source for that information, including what "most banks" means? As I say, it's not that I disbelieve your explanations, but I have found in practise most banks I deal with do not seem to be worried about it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to travel.SE. As you are a new user, I recommend you to look at our [tour](http://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help centre](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help), which explains how this site works. As you have been answering quite a few questions, you might also be interested in this [specific article about answers](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not answer the question, in which it is clear there is no card to put in the ATM.